# How to get spacing between two edit text boxes as the below attached image

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-custom-view, android-xml

[image: I want to know , how do I get the below style of result ?]

The texts can be entered into them . Only these two text widgets are possible in the given activity. I would want to know the structure , I would have to employ to get result as such.

I am still in learning phase.

Comment: create background shapes for edit texts

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need to replicate the exact design just like in the image? Or you just want to know how to put two edit texts one with single line and the other one in multiple lines that occupy the rest of the screen?

Comment: Use linear layout as holder (top layout) and mention orientation as vertical

Comment: @ljpv This would work as a template for every post , a user might want to make . In addition to the features you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways how to achieve that. I suggest you to start with reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) thoroughly to learn how to build layouts on Android.

In general, you can add spacing among views by adding some margin and/or padding.

If you want to replicate the particular design quickly, do this:

1. Have vertical [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) as your root layout (with gray background).
2. Add two [CardViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) (one for each box). That will add the 
   background and spacing.
3. Add other views to those CardViews.

Comment: what is the difference between recycler view and card view ?

Answer (score 0):

To give you something to work on

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"> //Elements inside this will be added vertically on the screen

      <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:hint="First edittext"/>

      <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:hint="Second edittext"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the basic structure on the image you showed. Expirement with it. Add your desired borders by using shapes and etc.